# How to locally install node module outside of node_modules directory?

Tags: node.js, npm, verdaccio

In order to deploy a dockerized service written in NodeJS I need to provide its plugins in a dedicated folder. The structure should look like this:

```
# plugin
/verdaccio/plugins/verdaccio-ldap
/verdaccio/plugins/verdaccio-ldap/package.json
/verdaccio/plugins/verdaccio-ldap/CHANGELOG.md
/verdaccio/plugins/verdaccio-ldap/index.js
/verdaccio/plugins/verdaccio-ldap/LICENSE
/verdaccio/plugins/verdaccio-ldap/README.md
# dependencies
/verdaccio/plugins/verdaccio-ldap/node_modules/.bin/ldapjs-add
/verdaccio/plugins/verdaccio-ldap/node_modules/.bin/ldapjs-compare
/verdaccio/plugins/verdaccio-ldap/node_modules/.bin/ldapjs-delete
/verdaccio/plugins/verdaccio-ldap/node_modules/.bin/ldapjs-modify
/verdaccio/plugins/verdaccio-ldap/node_modules/.bin/ldapjs-search
/verdaccio/plugins/verdaccio-ldap/node_modules/@types/ldapjs
/verdaccio/plugins/verdaccio-ldap/node_modules/@types/ldapjs/LICENSE
/verdaccio/plugins/verdaccio-ldap/node_modules/@types/ldapjs/README.md
/verdaccio/plugins/verdaccio-ldap/node_modules/@types/ldapjs/index.d.ts
/verdaccio/plugins/verdaccio-ldap/node_modules/@types/ldapjs/package.json

# rest ommited
```

However when I attempt to install it using `npm install verdaccio-ldap --prefix /verdaccio/plugins` it looks like this:

```
# plugin
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap/package.json
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap/CHANGELOG.md
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap/index.js
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap/LICENSE
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap/README.md
# dependencies
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/.bin/ldapjs-add
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/.bin/ldapjs-compare
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/.bin/ldapjs-delete
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/.bin/ldapjs-modify
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/.bin/ldapjs-search
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/@types/ldapjs
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/@types/ldapjs/LICENSE
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/@types/ldapjs/README.md
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/@types/ldapjs/index.d.ts
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/@types/ldapjs/package.json

# rest omitted
```

Can `npm install` handle this somehow? If not can I just `mv` the directories to where I need them without breaking dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

As per [npm-install Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), you can use `--global-style` which will cause npm to install the package into your local node_modules folder with the same layout it uses with the global node_modules folder. The dependencies of your package and everything they depend on will be flattened in their node_modules folder.

You cannot prevent the creation of node_modules with npm-install, but the layout will look like this:

```
# plugin
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap/package.json
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap/CHANGELOG.md
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap/index.js
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap/LICENSE
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap/README.md
# dependencies
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap/node_modules/.bin/ldapjs-add
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap/node_modules/.bin/ldapjs-compare
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap/node_modules/.bin/ldapjs-delete
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap/node_modules/.bin/ldapjs-modify
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap/node_modules/.bin/ldapjs-search
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap/node_modules/@types/ldapjs
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap/node_modules/@types/ldapjs/LICENSE
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap/node_modules/@types/ldapjs/README.md
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap/node_modules/@types/ldapjs/index.d.ts
/verdaccio/plugins/node_modules/verdaccio-ldap/node_modules/@types/ldapjs/package.json

# rest ommited
```